# Using CSS translateY()

Tags: css, translation

I am moving some element from (browser height + element height)px towards the top of the browser at -50px of the browser using CSS keyframes and that works but the problem is it's lagging and I am well aware that using translateY would resolve this issue.

Now assume I have a CSS as follows.

```
.bubble
{
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s ease-in-out;
}

.bubble.move
{
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50px);
}
```

As the element is below the browser screen (browser height + element height)px and I want it to move at the top of the screen at -50px, that doesn't work. It just moves the element from its current position to the -50px of that current position which is not intended. How can I ask transitions to go at -50px of the browser and not he element?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Use javascript to calculate it and set the css using javascript too

Comment: That is the option but I had an impression that CSS alone could do that

Comment: I've asked the same question some time ago and you can only move an element an x amount of pixels. you cannot tell it to go to specific coordinates. (which is really a pity). So for now, until css4 is released, you have to use javascript :).

Comment: also one more thing, is there a difference between translateY() and translate3d()? If the latter is used how can we ask it to ignore X and Z values for Y to work?

Comment: just set them to 0. but really there is no difference. translateY is just a sub section of translate3D.

Answer (score 2):

Translate isn't what you're looking for. You want to position the element absolutely and put the transition on the top property. Something like:

```
.bubble {
  position:absolute;
  top:100%;
  transition:top 1s ease-in-out;
}
.bubble.move {
  top:50px;
}
```

Only bad part about this approach is that the body will need to be the relative parent of the .bubble. I left out vendor prefixes because I hate them.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried positioning the element absolutely instead of relatively?

Comment: Yes never tried with relative position and it's just absolute from the starting